# WSO2 ESB and JSON in RESTfull Web Services

Tags: json, rest, apache-axis, wso2, wso2-esb

I´m using WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus 4.5.1.

I have a RESTful Web Service with Axis2, I want the response in JSON.

I followed de instruction here http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/add-json-support-wso2-wsas but the response is not JSON, is XML

Do I forget any step?

Any suggestion???

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable JSON message formatter to receive JSON response back
Check [this post](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2012/10/rest-support-in-wso2esb-handling-json.html),it explains how to send/receive json messages in wso2esb